# EXCEL: STDEV of a subset of data generated by mean

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have five values

```
643.8,
644.7,
632.4,
630.8,
627.9
```

of which the mean is `635.9`

I would like to get the three closest values to the mean, how do I do this with an excel formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution with two helper columns:

- in "diff to mean" enter this formula:
  `=ABS(A2-AVERAGE($A$2:$A$6))`
- and this for "rank":
  `=RANK.EQ(ABS(A2-AVERAGE($A$2:$A$6)),$B$2:$B$6,1)`

Now use this to get closest values:
`=INDEX($A$2:$A$6,MATCH(E2,$C$2:$C$6,0))`

[image]